# react-native Expo, integrar boton que ejecute una funcion a mi navegacion

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

intento integrar un boton en mi navegacion que no me envié a ninguna otra screen que solo ejecute la funcion `miFuncion()`.
en este caso intento que al tocar el `tab.Screen` con el `name` "buscador" no me envie a ningun lado solo ejecute `miFuncion()`, de ante mano muchas gracias.

````
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';

//icons link
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

//screens
import homeScreen from "./screens/homeScreen";
import postScreen from "./screens/postScreen";
import BuscadoScreen from "./screens/buscadorScreen";


const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {

 

  function miFuncion() {
    // Aquí va el código de tu función
    alert('Hola, soy una función');
  }

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="post" screenOptions={{ tabBarActiveTintColor: 'red' }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="+" component={homeScreen} options={{ tabBarIcon:({color, size})=>(<AntDesign name="home" size={24} color="black" />) }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="post" component={postScreen} options={{ tabBarIcon:({color, size})=>(<AntDesign name="setting" size={24} color="black" />) }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="buscador" component={BuscadoScreen} options={{ tabBarIcon:({color, size})=>(<AntDesign name="setting" size={24} color="black" />) }} />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}```
````